# How to create and print objects(with several attributes) from arraylist in java?

Tags: java, arrays, oop, object, arraylist

```
public class Hurricane
{
   private String name, month;
   private int year;
   private int cat;
   private int pressure;
   private double windspeed;

     
   
   //constructor - all private instance variables initialized
   public Hurricane(int y, String n, String m, int c, int p, double w) {
      this.year = y;
      this.name = n;
      this.month = m;
      this.cat = c;
      this.pressure = p;
      this.windspeed = w;
   }

   //accessor for year
   public int getYear() {
      return year; 
   }

   //accessor for name
   public String getName() {
      return name; 
   }
   
   //accessor for month
   public String getMonth() {
      return month;  
   }
   
   //accessor for category
   public int getCat() {
      return cat;  
   }
   
   //accessor for pressure
   public int getPressure() {
      return pressure;
   }
   
   //accessor for windspeed
   public double getWindspeed() {
      return windspeed;
   }
   
   //mutator for year
   public void setYear(int y) {
      year = y;
   }
   
   //mutator for name
   public void setName(String n) {
      name = n;
   }
   
   //mutator for month
   public void setMonth(String m) {
      month = m;
   }
   
   //mutator for category
   public void setCat(int c) {
      cat = c;
   }
   
   //mutator for pressure
   public void setPressure(int p) {
      pressure = p;
   }
   
   //mutator for windspeed
   public void setWindspeed (double w) {
      windspeed = w;
   }


   public String toString() {
       return "";
      // complete the toString method using String.format()  
   }
    
}
```

And Here is my Main method:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class HurricaneTester

{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //read data from text file & put in an array
        File fileName = new File("hurricanedata.txt");
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
        int numValues = 0;
        
        //count number of lines in text file
        while (inFile.hasNextLine() )
        {
            inFile.nextLine();
            numValues++;
        }
        inFile.close();
        
        
        //initialize arrays based on lines counted in text file
        int [] years = new int[numValues];
        String [] months = new String[numValues];
        int [] pressures = new int[numValues];
        double [] windSpeeds = new double[numValues];
        String [] names = new String[numValues];
        
        //read and assign data from text file to the arrays
        inFile = new Scanner(fileName);
        int index = 0;
        while(inFile.hasNext() )
        {
            years[index] = inFile.nextInt();
            months[index] = inFile.next();
            pressures[index] = inFile.nextInt();
            windSpeeds[index] = inFile.nextDouble();
            names[index] = inFile.next();
            index++;
        }
        inFile.close();
        //convert the windspeed, determine categories, calculate sums
        int [] cat = new int [numValues];
        int f = 0;
        for(double y : windSpeeds){// converts windspeed to mph
        y = y * 1.15078;
            if ((y >=74) && (y <= 98)){//Finds category of hurricane
            cat[f] = 1;
        }
        else if ((y >=99) && (y <= 110)){
            cat[f] = 2;
        }
        else if ((y >=111) && (y <= 129)){
            cat[f] = 3;
        }
        else if ((y >=130) && (y <= 156)){
            cat[f] = 4;
        }
        else if (y >=157){
            cat[f] =5;
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("Errors =");
        System.out.print(y);
        System.out.println("=");
        }
        f++;
        }
        //create a Hurricane ArrayList using the data above
        //Need to create Arraylist of obejcts 
        ArrayList<Hurricane> list = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0;i <= numValues; i++){
        list.add(new Hurricane(years[i],names[i],months[i],cat[i],pressures[i],windSpeeds[i]));
        //System.out.println(list);
        i++;
        }
        for (Hurricane ef: list) {//Prints Items from list
            System.out.println(ef);
        }
        //user prompted for range of years - not completed yet
        
        
        //print the data - not completed yet
     }
}
```

I`ve searched around on stack overflow and looked over many tutorials, my code just returns nothing after I try to print objects from it. The overall program goal is to take information from a file about hurricanes and depending on the year, display output from that time period. Thanks for any help! If you need clarification or more info, just let me know!

Comment: First of all, did you try to debug the code? is that reading file contents? and where exactly you are trying to print values

Comment: You have a method `toString()` where the comment clearly tells you you have to complete the implementation using `String.format` instead of just returning `""`. Do that.

Comment: Yes, i`m able to print the data from the arrays in the while loop. Im just trying to print the data(The objects i`m still trying to create) to the screen now.(I will format later). I just need to create an arraylist of Hurricane objects then display the objects and thier attributes.

Comment: You will be able to print them as soon as you have a proper implementation of the `toString` method.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, I need to create the objects beforehand then use my getter methods to display the output from there right? (I'm completing the method you suggested now.)

Comment: Thanks, @RealSkeptic, I'm just working out some bugs now

Comment: Why do you need all those temporary arrays if you have defined `Hurricane` class?  You can create instances of `Hurricane` while you are reading the file and add them to ArrayList.  It's a bit redundant to read the file just to count the lines to define the size of temporary arrays, then populate the arrays (which is likely to fail because `hasNext` is not called before each `next()/nextInt()`), then loop through arrays (and fail on `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` because of condition `i <= numValues`) and add `Hurricane` instances in the third round.